# How do I use this Prolog predicate so as to receive the result? Cannot figure out input

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

Our textbook gave us this example of a structurer for a math equation in Prolog:

```
math(Result) --> number(Number1), operator(Operator), number(Number2), { Result = [Number1, Operator, Number2] }.

operator('+') --> ['+'].

number('number') --> ['NUMBER'].
```

I'm quite new to Prolog, however, and I have no idea how to use this example to get the output. I'm under the impression it restructures the input using `Result` and outputs it for use.

The only input I've tried that doesn't cause an error is `math('number', '+', 'number').` but it always outputs `false` and I don't know why. Furthermore shouldn't it restructure it and give me the result in `Result` as well?

What should I be inputting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is a DCG. You should use the `phrase/2` interface predicate to access DCGs.

To find out what the DCG describes, start with the most general query, relating the nonterminal `math(R)` to a list `Ls` that is described by the first argument:

```
?- phrase(math(R), Ls).
```

From the answer you get (very easy exercise!), you will notice that `R` is probably not what you meant it to be. Hint: Look up `(=..)/2`.

Notice in particular that you need not be "inputting" anything here: A DCG *describes* a list. The list *can* be specified, but *need not* be given: A variable will do too! Think in terms of relations between arbitrary terms.